# How to solve a non-linear differential system with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, differential-equations, non-linear

I have a non-linear differential system :

- **(1)** `f''(t)=r(f(t))` and
- **(2)** `g''(t)=s(f(t),g(t))`

where `s(f(t),g(t))` may be `s(f(t),g(t))=f(t)*g(t)` or `s(f(t),g(t)) = cos(f(t))*sin(g(t))` ...  and we know g and s. I want to solve this system with Python but I don't know how. The first equation can be easily solved with `scipy.integrate.odeint` but I don't know how to solve the whole system.

Comment: I think you mean that `r` and `s` are known? How did you define the first order system for the first equation and why was that not applicable to the extended system?

Answer (score 1):

If you have given `r` and `s` as functions, then you can build the system as

```
def derivs(t,u): f,g, df, dg = u; return [ df, dg, r(f), s(f,g) ]
```

and

```
u = odeint(derivs, u0, t_array, tfirst=True)

f,g, df, dg = u.T
plt.plot(t_array,f, t_array,g)
```

or whatever you want to do with the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me please what is the order of the initial conditions ? Is u0=[f(t_array[0]),g(t_array[0]),df(t_array[0]),dg(t_array[0])] ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Of course, you could chose a different order of components, you just have to do it consistently everywhere.